# How to set value to taxvat in the Magento SOAP API?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

I need to set value to the taxvat field, the value needs to be the value from another field from my request.

For example:

When the client make request, all fields about taxvat needs to display the value from 'customer_cpf'.

I try this:

Function getAllowedAttributes from Mage_Customer_Model_Api_Resource

```
public function getAllowedAttributes($entity, array $filter = null)
{
    $attributes = $entity->getResource()
                    ->loadAllAttributes($entity)
                    ->getAttributesByCode();
    $result = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($this->_isAllowedAttribute($attribute, $filter)) {
            $result[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute;
            $result['taxvat'] = '080.443.119-33';
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I try to set taxvat with '080.443.119-33', but not works. Any idea?